# How to build a cms for a database?

Tags: content-management-system, couchdb

something similar to futon for couchdb?

also where is the source code fo futon?

is it FOSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for Futon is included in the CouchDB project. It is pretty much a completely independent project, so you will get lots of knowledge and experience by looking at it. (Of course, it is only *useful* with CouchDB--that is why the source code is inside the CouchDB project.)

If you download the CouchDB source code, Futon will be in the `share/www/` folder: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/tree/1.1.1/share/www